# How to pass video from 1st activity to 2nd activity when a button clicked? - android studio

Tags: android-studio

In Activity1 I've a Button and videoView. When the button is clicked Activity2 is started.

In Activity2 I've a videoview2.

I want to display the video retrieved from videoView in Activity1 going to the videoview2 in Activity2 .

can someone help me with the code to make this work?

Comment: Look up intents and putExtra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get the video file retrieved in a `String` or `Uri`. Make that object *static*, by putting the word static. You can then access the the static object by `Activity1.object_name` in the 2nd activity.

Comment: tnx for the answer, does you know how to convert to uri or to path, the content of the videoview?

Comment: No need for that. The Video view can accept uri objects.